# Mongodb - aggregate query against array of objects where key value equals true

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents called items which each have within them a field:value as so:

```
{
  likes: [
    0: {
      like: false
      actor: { Object }
    },
    1: {
      like: true
      actor: { Object }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I need to return documents based on whether or not the document has or does not have any likes.

The likes array starts off as empty. If a person likes an item the likes array will have a new object added to it containing `like:true` and the relevant actor details. If the same person removes the like that particular object will be updated to say `like:false`.

In viewing the results a person has the option to be able to query only the documents which do or do not have likes.

**Expected outcome**
With likes - Query should return only the documents which have 1 or more likes. This is defined as: the likes array must have at least 1 object where like:true exists.
Without likes - Query should return only the documents which have 0 likes. This is defined as: the likes array must be empty or there must be 0 objects where like:true exists.

```
{ item: A, likes: [] }
{ item: B, likes: [{ like: false, actor: Beth }, { like: false: actor: John }] }
{ item: C, likes: [{ like: true, actor: Jeff }, { like: true: actor: Jess }] }
{ item: D, likes: [{ like: false, actor: Bob }] }
{ item: E, likes: [{ like: false, actor: AJ }, { like: true: actor: Raluca }] }
{ item: F, likes: [{ like: true, actor: Craig }] }
```

With likes - Query should return items C + E + F
Without likes - Query should return items A + B + D

How can I make this happen?

**Previous attempt**

The current logic tried fails as it is only checking the length of the array. If a user removes a like it immediately returns the wrong results.

```
matchQueryConditions.$and.push({
  $expr: { [searchOptions.withLikes === true ? '$gt' : '$eq']: [{ $size: '$likes' }, 0] },
});
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you add an example please?

Comment: @J.F. Expected outcome added. Let me know if this is not clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) for the umpteenth time it finally clicked and the answer turned out to be relatively simple. The following tweak fixed it:

```
matchQueryConditions.$and.push({
    'likes.like' : {
      [searchOptions.withLikes === true ? '$eq' : '$ne']: true
    }
});
```